# Como inserir várias linhas de texto à direita de uma figura no rmarkdown?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Preciso adicionar linhas de texto ao lado direito de uma figura no `rmarkdown`e não estou conseguindo quebrar as linhas de maneira que as mesmas fiquem alinhadas uma abaixo da outra. Abaixo segue o chunck atual:

```
---
title: "UFPR"
author: "Departamento de Nutrição"
date: "17/12/2021"
output: html_document
---

![](https://servicos.nc.ufpr.br/PortalNC/painel/assets/img/logos/logo_ufpr.jpg)**Universidade Federal do Paraná**  
**Departamento de Ciências da Saúde**  
**Faculdade de Nutrição**
```

A saída está retornando isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, preciso que retorne assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que a resposta dependerá do tipo de documento que será exportado. Não deve haver uma resposta universal para esta pergunta. O objetivo final é gerar um html, pdf ou docx?

Comment: Desculpe Marcus, eu desconsiderei isto pelo fato de acreditar que o `Knitr` não faria distinção de funções em detrimento da saída. De todo modo, adicionei ao chunk o que você sugeriu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Tente colocar a sua figura e o seu texto de interesse entre `::: {.floatting}` e `:::`;
2. Considere utilizar a função `include_graphics()` do pacote `knitr` para controlar os parâmetros da imagem através das opções do chunk.

````
::: {.floatting}

```{r out.width='17%', out.extra='style="float:left; padding:2px"'}

knitr::include_graphics("https://servicos.nc.ufpr.br/PortalNC/painel/assets/img/logos/logo_ufpr.jpg")
````

**Universidade Federal do Paraná**
**Departamento de Ciências da Saúde**
**Faculdade de Nutrição**

:::

Resultado:

[image: ufpr_logo]